# Speaker not working of laney lionheart

Tags: guitar, amplifiers, speakers

I have a laney lionheart mini amp, and a fender squire bullet strat.  I connected my guitar to the amp and switched it on, but no sound came from the speaker; then I connected my headphone to the jack, and the amp was working just fine, but again, no sound is coming from my speaker, what shall I do? Any opinions?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ideas. The jack for headphones is usually a switched socket: plugging in a jack will disconnect the speaker from the circuit. It may be that the contacts on that socket are not re-connecting when the jack is removed. Switch cleaner often works to re-instate things.

I've also come across the same sort of problem with the jack sockets for send/return.

Of course, it may be that the speaker itself has died. That can be checked by disconnecting the two wires, and connecting a small battery instead. As it's connected, the cone should move in or out. Also, if there's a jack for extension speaker, that again is often a switched socket, disconnecting the internal speaker. Same remedy as previous. Or, it could be as simple as a wire has come off the speaker...